# iCloud: How can I create a calendar event for next 3 days for a specific time?

Tags: iphone, icloud, calendar

Is there a quick way to make calendar events for 3 days in a row for like 8am to 4pm without having to make 3 seperate events?

Eg.  Make event for 8am to 4pm and repeat for next 3 days ONLY.

Can't see anyway of doing this using the iPhone interface or the iCloud interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an Event, and then select "Repeat => Every Day" and click "Done" - you'll now see a new option below "Repeat" called "End Repeat" where you then choose e.g. a date 3 days from today.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes but the repeat option is like for everyday... I just want it to repeat 2 times for a total of 3 days.

Comment: You'll get that option as the next option below "Repeat" - just try it out.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  I never tried selecting every day because I didn't think new options would exist!  You should clarify it in your answer to include new options will appear etc... anyways thank!

Answer (score 3):

Create a new event in iOS 5 Calender and select "Repeat":

[image]

Set repeat to "Daily" and go back to "Add Event" dialog. Now you can select either an end date for the repetition or set it to "forever":

[image]